# how to disable button using JavaScript addEventListener() method?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, dom-events

I was looking for how to disable button using JS and I find this and it works:

```
<button id="startbtn" onclick="this.disabled=true; pausebtn.disabled=false; stopbtn.disabled=false;">Start</button>
```

but I want to disable it using addEventListener() method instead of doing it directly on the html div, but it is not working, is it posible?

```
let start1 = document.getElementById('startbtn');
        start1.addEventListener('click', start);
        start1.addEventListener('click', this.disabled = true);
```

Obs: the second line in the code above starts the "start" function which is a cronometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Element.currentTarget.setAttribute(name, value)` method more details about the function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```js
let start1 = document.getElementById('startbtn');
start1.addEventListener('click', start);
start1.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.currentTarget.setAttribute('disabled', true));
```

It is tested & working.
let me know if you have any issues with the snippet above.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a callback.

If you didn't already have a reference to the button use the `currentTarget` property of the event object that gets passed into the callback.

```js
start1.addEventListener('click',() => start1.disabled = true);
```

Comment: You should update your explanation since you're not using `currentTarget`  This is easier to read. You would only use `currentTarget` if you didn't already have a reference or if you wanted to make your handler reusable.

Comment: Haha! Thanks friend. Forgot to update it after the updating the code :)